# Ubuntu 22 autoinstall with UEFI and RAID1

Tags: 22.04, autoinstall

I try to install ubunutu 22 via autoinstall but he throws a error:
Missing two required arguments fstype and volume

this is my storage config:

```
storage:
    config:
# Partition table of two disks
    - { ptable: gpt, path: /dev/sda, wipe: superblock-recursive, preserve: false, name: '', grub_device: true, type: disk, id: disk-sda }
    - { ptable: gpt, path: /dev/sdb, wipe: superblock-recursive, preserve: false, name: '', grub_device: true, type: disk, id: disk-sdb }

    - { device: disk-sda, flag: bios_grub, grub_device: false, id: partition-0, number: 1, preserve: false, size: 1048576, type: partition }
    - { device: disk-sdb, flag: bios_grub, grub_device: false, id: partition-1, number: 1, preserve: false, size: 1048576, type: partition }

    - { device: disk-sda, size: 536870912, wipe: superblock, flag: boot, number: 2, preserve: false, grub_device: true, type: partition, id: partition-2 }
    - { device: disk-sdb, size: 536870912, wipe: superblock, flag: boot, number: 2, preserve: false, grub_device: true, type: partition, id: partition-3 }
 
    - { device: disk-sda, size: 8589934592, wipe: superblock, flag: '', number: 3, preserve: false, grub_device: false, type: partition, id: partition-4 }
    - { device: disk-sdb, size: 8589934592, wipe: superblock, flag: '', number: 3, preserve: false, grub_device: false, type: partition, id: partition-5 }

    - { device: disk-sda, size: -1, wipe: superblock, flag: '', number: 4, preserve: false, grub_device: false, type: partition, id: partition-6 }
    - { device: disk-sdb, size: -1, wipe: superblock, flag: '', number: 4, preserve: false, grub_device: false, type: partition, id: partition-7 }

    - { name: md0, raidlevel: raid1, devices: [ partition-2, partition-3 ], spare_devices: [], preserve: false, wipe: superblock, ptable: gpt, type: raid, id: raid-0 }
    - { device: raid-0, size: 530870912, wipe: superblock, flag: 'boot', number: 1, preserve: false, grub_device: true, type: partition, id: partition-8 }
    - { fstype: fat32, volume: partition-8, preserve: false, type: format, id: format-3 }
    - { path: /boot/efi, device: format-3, type: mount, id: mount-2 }

    - { name: md1, raidlevel: raid1, devices: [ partition-4, partition-5 ], spare_devices: [], preserve: false, wipe: superblock, ptable: gpt, type: raid, id: raid-1 }
    - { device: raid-1, size: 8583934592, wipe: superblock, flag: swap, number: 2, preserve: false, grub_device: false, type: format, id: partition-9}
    - { fstype: swap, volume: partition-9, preserve: false, type: format, id: format-4 }
    - { path: '', device: format-4, type: mount, id: mount-3 }

    - { name: md2, raidlevel: raid1, devices: [ partition-6, partition-7 ], spare_devices: [], preserve: false, wipe: superblock, ptable: gpt, type: raid, id: raid-2 }
    - { device: raid-2, size: -1, wipe: superblock, flag: '', number: 3, preserve: false, grub_device: false, type: partition, id: partition-10 }
    - { fstype: ext4, volume: partition-10, preserve: false, type: format, id: format-5 }
    - { path: /, device: format-5, type: mount, id: mount-4 }
```

Comment: Did you try adding the two required arguments fstype and volume?